# What to do when USB device is loaded with drivers of another device?

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

I have an augmented reality headset (Meta 2) installed on a windows 10 Pro computer and it works great. It interfaces with the computer through USB.

Then I have a second, completely unrelated USB device (a ultrasound probe) for which I also successfully installed the drivers - however, if I connect the device to the computer, I can see in the device manager that the device I plug in is listed as "Cypress FX2LP No EEPROM Device" and when I look at the properties->driver->driver details I see that it loads the drivers of the Meta headset. Obviously the probe doesn't work (no driver error is shown however in the device manager).

If I use the probe on a system that does not have the drivers of the Augmented Reality headset installed, the probe works.

How can this happen and how can I force this device to use the right drivers?

Comment: What are the Hardware IDs (as shown in Details tab of the Device Manager) for both devices ? Please check this on a system where the correct driver is loaded for the device.

Comment: Cannot find confirmation but the Meta Headset may also be built on the same Cypress FX2LP kit that the probe is using. Have you tried doing a manual install (the "have disk method") of the proper drivers for the probe to see if you can get them each using the proper ones? I suspect this will just set them both to use the manual driver, but I am not certain of that.

Comment: Apparently both of your devices use the same USB bridge - Cypress FX2LP, using same VID and PID. The device ID should be different, and some other strings. Check with USBTreeView tool how the device descriptors are different. If they are identical (sloppy hardware), then you are likely out of luck. If different, there might be a way to patch INF files for one or another driver.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such problem, you can manually install the driver for your Probe.

Open Device Manger and choose to update the Probe device-browse my computer for driver software, then you can choose the correct driver for the device
[image]

Comment: When I do that, I'm getting the message "The best drivers for your device are already installed"

Comment: what if you uninstall it in Device Manager,then menually install the correct driver for it? Or I think you can firstly remove the drivers of the Meta headset, then plug the device Probe, seeing if it will load correctly.